# Client and Server Socket Programming in C Unix

Tags: c, sockets, unix, client

I have a client and a server on the same machine(using sockets). A command is supposed to send from client to server, for example `ls -l /`.

Server should receive the command, running it in the shell and send the result back to the client. The user should see the result (in this case the result of `ls -l`) on his screen e.g on the client's screen.

When you type the `ls -l /` or `dir /` the list of files appears on the server screen , not the client screen.

What is the problem?

PS. to test the program you have to compile both client and server (`gcc -o myclient client.c`) running each on a separated terminal.

```
/* client
** echoc.c -- the echo client for echos.c; demonstrates unix sockets
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"

int main(void)
{

  int s, t, len;
  struct sockaddr_un remote;
  char str[100];

  if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Client is trying to connect...\n");

  remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
  len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
  if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
    perror("connect");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Connected.\n");

  while(printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin)) {
    if (send(s, str, strlen(str), 0) == -1) {
      perror("send");
      exit(1);
    }

    if ((t=recv(s, str, 100, 0)) > 0) {
      str[t] = '\0';
      printf("Result> %s", str);
    } else {
      if (t < 0) perror("recv");
      else printf("Server closed connection\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  close(s);

  return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
      /*
** echos.c -- the echo server for echoc.c; demonstrates unix sockets
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"



void doit(char *client_message,char **argv)
{

    while (*client_message != '\0') //kör tills man stöter på '\0' (end of line)
    {
        while (*client_message == ' ' || *client_message == '\t' || *client_message == '\n') //så länge den nuvarande karaktären i filen är ' ', '\t' eller '\n'
            *client_message++ = '\0'; //sätt den till '\0'
        *argv++ = client_message; //gå vidare till nästa karaktär
        while (*client_message != '\0' && *client_message != ' ' &&
                *client_message != '\t' && *client_message != '\n')
            client_message++;
    }
    *argv = '\0';
}

int runit(char **argv)
{


    pid_t child;
    int status;
    bool waiting;
    child=fork();
    if (child==0)
    {
        if(execvp(*argv,argv)<0)
            return 0 ;
    }
    else if (child <0)
    {
        return -1;

    }
    else
    {
        waiting = true;
        while(waiting)
        {
            if(wait(&status))
                waiting = false;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}



int main(void)

{
    int s, s2, t, len,*argv[80];
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    char str[100];

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(s, 5) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;)
    {
        int done, n;
        printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1)
        {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Connected.\n");

        done = 0;
        do
        {
            n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);
            if (n <=0)
            {
                if (n < 0) perror("recv");
                done = 1;
            }

            if (!done)
            {

                /** a call doit from here **/

                doit(str,argv);
                runit(argv);



                if (send(s2, argv, n, 0) < 0)
                {
                    perror("send");
                    done = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        while (!done);

        close(s2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - provide specific questions.  "I cannot go any further" is not a constructive question.

Comment: First, welcome to StackOverflow.  I would like to help you but you have not given any details to what your question actually is.  Does this particular code not work?  If not how is it broken and how would you like the code to work.  Try and be specific.

Comment: is it understandable now ?

Comment: ` user type ls -1 for a command a list of the files will be seen on the screen , `  where is your client?

Comment: the code is up there man ! take a look plz ! (both server and client is there) :))

Answer (score 0):

1. Transfer the **ls -l** to the server
2. Do a `popen()`. Eg : `fp = popen(cmd, "r");`
3. Transfer the contents of the pointer `fp` to the client.